# ttf-mscorefonts-installer won't complete

Tags: apt, software-installation, fonts, .ttf

This is just the simplest of the attempts made. Hopefully there are clues in there that someone can follow.

On Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit:

```
roger@roger-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for roger:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 329314 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted
Unpacking ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) over (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.2) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Get:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [198 kB]
Fetched 198 kB in 2s (66.5 kB/s)
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/arial32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https://cytranet.dl.sourceforge.net/.../corefonts/the fonts/final/arial32.exe The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
roger@roger-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

That's due to [a bug in Apt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1570141). To install it, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo chown -R _apt:root /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial
```

Comment: interesting comment. Is there a bug report for this? I get another problem now: [start-quote] Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
E: Failed to fetch https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl [end-quote]

Comment: @AndreaBorga try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/861410/616451 making sure to run `sudo apt install -f` afterwards.