# How to check if a software version exists for my Ubuntu release?

Tags: updates, launchpad

I'm having the issue in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852302/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-ttf-mscorefonts-installer). Looking at the [accepted solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/852727/519931), it says:

> Check on Launchpad whether version 1.3.4 (Yakkety) or 1.2.19 (Xenial) was made available for your Ubuntu release.

Looking at Xenial releases, it has:

- 1.2.19
- 1.2.15ubuntu0.2
- 1.2.20
- 1.2.15ubuntu0.2

I would assume that because 1.2.19 doesn't have "ubuntu" appended, that the release is not compatible, but because 1.2.20 also doesn't have anything appended, I'm not sure what this means. What's the correct way of checking if a software version in Launchpad is compatible with my Ubuntu version (16.04)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The Launchpad page for apt means exactly what it says. The latest version of apt from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories is 1.2.19 which you can verify from the terminal using the command:

```
apt-cache policy apt
```

The results of `apt-cache policy apt` also show the other two non-proposed versions of apt (1.2.10ubuntu1 and 1.2.15ubuntu0.2) and the version of apt that is currently used is marked  as *Installed* and also marked by asterisks.

apt 1.2.20 is a proposed update that has not been released yet. The other two versions of apt in the list are old versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 16.04 (Xenial), a look on the [Ubuntu Xenial packages page for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) shows 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 as the latest version in **multiverse**, and for your `apt` question it is 1.2.19 for [Ubuntu Xenial packages for `apt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial-updates/apt) as the latest version in **xenial-updates**.

So, you are good to go in terms of the needed version, and you have checked the version number on the official page.